# Are we comparing the expectation of random variables in "convergence in probability"?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/HsNVjCDI9ts) and [this](https://youtu.be/Ajar_6MAOLw) to try to understand what convergence in probability means.
In the first video, I was confused at why, in the Excel demonstration, the random variables had their standard deviations depend on $n$. Isn't this law/phenomenon supposed to hold even if my sequence ${X_1, X_2,...X_n}$ was just $n$ standard normal distributions? In which case, what makes it so that $X_n$ is so much closer to our $c$ (or $a$ from the second video) than $X_{n-1}$?

I can understand a normal sequence $A = \{a_1, a_2,...a_n\}$ converges to $1$ if $a_n=1 - \frac{1}{n}$, as is a common example. But if we use an example of a sequence of $n$ standard normal variables, why is $X_n$ any closer to the mean (zero) than $X_1$? Isn't it the mean of the sequence that's supposed to be close to zero?

My initial understanding was that say I have a set of trials of stnd random variables that turned out to be $\{1, 2, -1, -2, 3\}$. In this case the mean is $0.6$. If I had a waaay bigger samples size $\{1, 2, -1, -2, 3, 2, -1, 3, -2,....\}$ I would eventually get the mean to $0.0$. But based on the first video it looks like each term itself is getting closer to zero (in the video it was closer to 1), implying it's more like $\{1, 2, -1, -2, 3, 2, -2, 1, -1, 1, 1,...\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is not about the central limit theorem as you seem to imply with your question. No averages are taken. The random variables in the video are independent normal variables with mean 1 and decreasing variance.

"But if we use an example of a sequence of  standard normal variables, why is $X_n$ any closer to the mean (zero) than $X_1$?" If their variances were positive and constant, then you are correct, you wouldn't expect the sequence to converge.

At no point is the values of the sequence summed up and divided by the length of the sequence.

Comment: oh ok, so I got the two concepts mixed up then? I guess this is why nobody used standard normals in the examples. However, one book did, but instead of converging on a constant $c$ they said it converges to $X$. Is this true?

Comment: It is context dependent. You would need to provide a reference to the book.

Comment: Oh, then it's pg. 72 of ["All of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21736-9).